# Skip list in java

Tags: java, skip-lists

I was going through data structures in java under the topic `Skip list` and I came across the following:

In a skip list of `n nodes`, for each `k` and `i` such that `1 ≤ k ≤lg n` and `1 ≤ i ≤
n/2k–1⎦ – 1`, the node in position `2k–1` · `i` points to the node in position `2k–1` · (`i + 1`).
This means that every second node points to the node two positions ahead, every
fourth node points to the node four positions ahead, and so on, as shown in Figure
3.17a. This is accomplished by having different numbers of reference fields in nodes
on the list: Half of the nodes have just one reference field, one-fourth of the nodes
have two reference fields, one-eighth of the nodes have three reference fields, and so
on. The number of reference fields indicates the level of each node, and the number of
levels is `maxLevel = ⎣lg n⎦ + 1`.

And the figure is :
A skip list with (a) evenly and (b) unevenly spaced nodes of different levels;
(c) the skip list with reference nodes clearly shown.

[image]

I don't understand the mathematical part and what exactly the sktip list is and even nodes?

Comment: It is like a SortedMap. You can find a value in it in O(log(n)) time. Usually it has similar or smaller memory footprint than a TreeMap, but I guess it has worse memory locality because of its variation of array length.

Comment: @GáborBakos Can't agree with you here. O(log(n)) is only achievable in case you make a O(n) operation to balance it, otherwise O(log(n)) is only expected lookup, not worst-case

Comment: @xyz btw, have you tried the Wiki article on Skip List? It seems to be better written than the thing you were reading.

Comment: @Ordous Thanks for the correction, you are right, the O(log(n)) is just the expected, not the worst-case scenario.

Comment: @Ordous Not yet..I was going through the book Data Structures And Algoriths in Java by Adam Drozdek

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok let me try to make you understand this.

A skip list is a data-structure which definitely makes your searches faster in a list of given  elements.

A better analogy would be a network of subway in any of the bigger cities. Imagine there are 90 stations to cover and there are different lines (Green, Yellow and Blue).

The Green line only connects the stations numbered 0, 30, 60 and 90
The Yellow line connects 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 and 90
The blue line connects all the station from 0 through 90.

If you want to board the train at station 0 and want to get down at 75. What is the best strategy?

Common sense would suggest to board a train on Green line from station 0 and get down at station 60.
Board another train on Yellow line from station 60 and get down at station 70.
Board another train on Blue line from station 70 and get down at 75.

Any other way would have been more time consuming.

Now replace the stations with the nodes and lines with three individual lists (the set of these lists are called skip list).

And just imaging that you wanted to search an element at a node containing the value 75.

I hope this explains what Skip Lists are and how they are efficient.

In the traditional approach of searching, you could have visited each node and got to 75 in 75 hops. 
In case of binary search you would have done it in logN
In skip list you can do the same in 1 + 1 + 15 in our particular case. You can do the math, seems to be simple though :)

**EDIT: Evenly spaced nodes & Unevenly spaced nodes**
As you can see my analogy, it has equal number of stations between each node on each line. 
This is evenly spaced nodes. It is an ideal situation.

To understand it better we need to understand the creation of Skip Lists.

In the early stages of its construction there is only one list (the blue line) and each new node is first added to the list at an appropriate location. When the number of nodes in the blue line increases then there comes a need to create another list (yellow line) and promote one of the nodes to list 2. (PS: The first and the last element of list 1 is always promoted to the newly added list in the skip lists set). Hence, the moment a new list is added it will have three nodes.

**Promotion Strategy** : How to find out which node to promote from the bottom most list(blue line) to the upper lists (yellow line and green line).

The best way to decide is randomly :) So lets say upon addition of a new node, we flip a coin to see if it can be promoted to  the second list. if yes, then we add it to the second list and then flip a coin again to check if it has to be added in the third list or not.

So you see, if you use this random mechanism, there might arrive situations where the nodes are unevenly spaced. :)

Hope this helps.

[image: Diagram of Blue, Yellow, Green trains, and route taking Blue train from 0 to 60, Yellow train from 60 to 70, and finally Blue train from 70 to 71, 72, 73, 74, and 75.]

Comment: As there is no weight in the lines in your example, it can not be assumed that it is fastest to go the way you suggest. Perhaps you can add more information where you make some assumptions.

Comment: thanks for the comment. definitely what you are saying makes a lot sense. I was just trying to simplify an example. Will try to add a link with better detailed explanation. :)

Comment: Nice way of explaining it, though

Comment: @dharam thanks for explaining..however I would be really grateful if you could add a little detail of evenly and unevenly space nodes...

Comment: @xyz See EDIT for the answer :)

Comment: @dharam Thanks for the edit.Can you tell me which book you have used for the reference..The explanantion is pretty simple..

Comment: Well... If you want to learn it, use MIT Video Lectures for Datastructures and Algorithms

Comment: You said “1 + 1 + 15 in our particular case”. Wouldn’t it be five, not fifteen, 1 + 1 + 5? Green to 60, Yellow to 70, then Blue to 71, 72, 73, 74, and lastly 75.